# Display error message depending on response from backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'have a form which has date of birth filed. I want to show error message when I get response back from my php script. My php is script working fine, I'm getting response when there are multiple element as an array. like this.

```
[{code: 0, message: "Please fill valid date of birth."}, {code: 1, message: ""}]
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
```

I want show error message only on the element which has a response 0. At the moment error message showing on all element even some element has response code 1. I want to validate the each field separately and error message should be shown on the element which has code:0.

**Here is my JS code**

```
//GET JSON from Validation.php and extract the nodes
  var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var parseJson = JSON.parse(response);
  var resultCode = parseJson.code;
  var resultMessage = parseJson.message;
  console.log(parseJson);
  var element = document.getElementById('stepbirth');
  element.classList.toggle("disabled", parseJson.some(resp => !resp.code))

   //Show Validation Message
      parseJson.map(response => {

        var items = document.getElementsByClassName("stepbirthVal"),i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
          items[i].innerHTML = response.message;
        }
      });
```

Till toggle class my code is working fine, only error message is not showing how I want. It should only on a element which has response code 0.

Comment: That part is working fine. I have issue only with Show validation message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a forEach in plain JS

Since the message is empty when it is "1", we should take advantage of that and fill the span with that empty string

```js
const parseJson = [{
  code: 0,
  message: "Please fill valid date of birth."
}, {
  code: 1,
  message: "OK" // or blank
}]

const items = document.querySelectorAll(".stepbirthVal");
parseJson.forEach((response, i) => items[i].innerHTML = response.code === 0 ? response.message : "");

// OR just
// parseJson.forEach((response, i) => items[i].innerHTML = response.message);
```

```html
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
<hr/>
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
```

jQuery:

```js
const parseJson = [{
  code: 0,
  message: "Please fill valid date of birth."
}, {
  code: 1,
  message: ""
}]

const $items = $(".stepbirthVal");
$.each(parseJson,(i,response) => $items.eq(i).html(response.message))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span><hr/>
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your html and response structure I'd advise you to iterate over your response and for those with message only use code as array element index. Smth like this:

```js
const respMock = [{
  code: 0,
  message: "Please fill valid date of birth."
}, {
  code: 1,
  message: ""
}];

const inputs = $('.date_of_birth');

respMock.forEach(function(resp) {
  if (resp.message) {
    let errorSpan = $(inputs[resp.code]).next();
    errorSpan.text(resp.message);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" value="" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
```

Comment: Since the spans have classes too and each corresponds to one entry in the array, the code can be [somewhat simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304616/295783)